# Sql Update on Row_Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with few columns say,

```
FirstName, Lastname, Phonenumber, Accesslevel
AA ,          BB  ,    +447000000000,  AL1
CC ,          DD ,     +447800000000 , AL2
AA  ,         BB  ,    +447000000000 , AL3
```

If the phoneNumbers and Lastname are same, I want the below results (I mean I need to Update the table instead of just select)

```
FirstName, Lastname, Phonenumber, Accesslevel
AA ,          BB  ,    +447000000000,  AL1, AL3
CC ,          DD ,     +447800000000 , AL2
AA  ,         BB  ,    +447000000000 , AL3
```

The script I have doesn't do what i Want,

````
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
SET [AccessLevel] = stuff ( ( SELECT
                          ', ' + [ExtAccessLevelIDList]
                  FROM
                          [Table] t1
                  where t1.PhoneNumber = t2.PhoneNumber
        FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ) , 1 , 1, '' )
from [Table] t2```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you care about both the telephone number and name, you need equality on both those columns:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET [AccessLevel] = STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + [ExtAccessLevelIDList]
                                FROM [Table] t1
                                WHERE t1.PhoneNumber = t2.PhoneNumber AND
                                      t1.LastName = t2.LastName
                                FOR XML PATH ( '' )
                               ), 1, 2, ''
                             )
    FROM (SELECT t2.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, PhoneNumber ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
          FROM [Table] t2
         ) t2
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:

More recent versions of SQL Server support `string_agg()` which makes this much simpler:

```
update [table]
    set AccessLevel = tt.accesslevel
    from (select phonenumber, lastname,
                 string_agg(ExtAccessLevelIDList, ', ') as accesslevel
          from [table]
          group by phonenumber, lastname
         ) tt
    where tt.phonenumber = [table].phonenumber and
          tt.lsatname = [table].lastname;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon But this script updates both the row corresponding to that PhoneNumber. I want to update only the first row.

Comment: String_agg doesn't work as the server is 2012

Comment: @Jeni . . . Is the question tagged "sql-server-2012"?  There is no "first row" in a table, unless a column specifies the ordering.  I have updated the answer to change an *arbitrary* row for each name/phone combination for the update.

Comment: Sorry Just tagged the question for sq-server-2012.
Also I want to update only first row in the sense, I meant I wanted to update only one row. But the script is updating both the rows having same phone number.

Comment: @Jeni . . . I already fixed that in the first version of the query.